# Service error: Spreadsheets (line 4, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script

I am very new to Google Scripts and pulled this script from another user months ago. It has worked fine for a long time and now all of a sudden I am getting an error.

Service error: Spreadsheets (line 4, file "Code")

Can anyone tell me what I need to change to fix this? The script is designed to copy a template sheet and then copy all the protections with it. I had to update the template recently, but I have done that before with no issues.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the debugger and error]

```
function duplicateSheetWithProtections() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  sheet = ss.getSheetByName('New School Temp');    
  sheet2 = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName('My Copy');
  var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    var p = protections[i];
    var rangeNotation = p.getRange().getA1Notation();
    var p2 = sheet2.getRange(rangeNotation).protect();
    p2.setDescription(p.getDescription());
    p2.setWarningOnly(p.isWarningOnly());
    if (!p.isWarningOnly()) {
      p2.removeEditors(p2.getEditors());  // remove editors 
      p2.addEditors(p.getEditors());      // except those permitted for original
      // p2.setDomainEdit(p.canDomainEdit()); //  only if using an Apps domain 
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("My Copy").activate(); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do not post screenshots of errors, post them as a part of your question

Comment: Does a sheet with that name already exist? You cant name a sheet the exact same as another sheet.